# Question about Pi3 and UART finger printer

Tags: pi-3, uart

I have a Pi3 board and a UART Fingerprint that brand is Waveshare link is https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/UART_Fingerprint_Reader

but When I receive it I have totally no idea how to use pi3 to read the fingerprint does anyone can give me some ideas?

Answer (score 1):

- There is a link to the sample code in [there](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/File:UART-Fingerprint-Reader-Code.7z). the zip appears to have the firmware for the mcu controlling the reader and a visual c++ program that connects to it.
- The user manual [here](https://www.waveshare.com/w/upload/6/65/UART-Fingerprint-Reader-UserManual.pdf) contains the serial port protocol. You could get started writing a python script that sends out a sequence of bytes as documented and checking for the appropriate responses.
- Found a [tutorial](https://tutorials-raspberrypi.com/how-to-use-raspberry-pi-fingerprint-sensor-authentication/) as well

Comment: Thanks for your reply but both they need another model like the uart to usb model. Is that possible just use Pi3 and fingerprinter model get communication?

Comment: @panda001 according to the tutorial using a USB TTL adapter is recommended but not mandatory. It makes sense when working with devices working with incompatible voltages (atmega8 typically uses 5v, RPi uses only 3.3v etc) or communicating over distances that TTL cannot carry reliably. From what i can see the MCU chip used is a [STM32F205RC](http://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers/stm32f205rc.html) that operates at 1.8 to 3.3v according to its datasheet. As MCU pins are directly exposed, they should operate at the same voltages at the Pi and should work provided the wiring is correct

Comment: @panda001 also see the [schematic](https://www.waveshare.com/w/upload/7/75/UART-Fingerprint-Reader-Schematic.pdf), the module does operate on 3.3v input